# Custom DataGridView Column In Visual Basic?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a custom DataGridViewColumn and DataGridViewCell, and have found [this](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0707061) article to be a great resource. I'm done creating the DataGridViewColumn class and the DataGridViewCell class, however, when I try to edit the type of the column, my new custom classes don't show up as one of the options. My DataGridViewScheduleColumn inherits DataGridViewColumn, so I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong. Is there anything else I need to do to expose these classes to the IDE?

Thanks.

Here is the custom column class

```
Public Class DataGridViewScheduleColumn
    Inherits DataGridViewColumn


Public Sub New()
    Me.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewScheduleCell
    Me.ReadOnly = True
End Sub

Public MaxValue As Long
Private needsRecalc As Boolean = True

Public Sub calcMaxValue()
    If needsRecalc Then
        Dim colIndex As Integer = Me.DisplayIndex
        For rowIndex As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = Me.DataGridView.Rows(rowIndex)
            MaxValue = Math.Max(MaxValue, CLng(row.Cells(colIndex).Value))

        Next
        needsRecalc = False
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Is your custom DGV column and cell code in a different project than the Form you're trying to use them on?

If so, you need to add a reference to your custom DGV column project from your Form project.  Do so by right clicking your Form project, select 'Add Reference...' from the context menu and add the DGV column project (or the project's output).

Comment: They're in the same project, not sure why I can't see them.